# Uniqueness of the tensor product decomposition of subfactors

Tags: oa.operator-algebras, von-neumann-algebras, subfactors

A subfactor $(N \subset M)$ is  **indecomposable**  if (for $N_i \subset M_i)$:    $$(N \subset M) = (N_1 \otimes N_2  \subset M_1 \otimes M_2)  \Rightarrow \exists i \  N_i = M_i$$ 
Then, a subfactor $(N \subset M)$ decomposes into a tensor product of indecomposable subfactors:$$(N \subset M) = (\bigotimes_i N_i \subset \bigotimes_i M_i)$$with $(N_i \subset M_i)$ indecomposable.

**Question**: Is this decomposition unique  for the  finite index finite depth irreducible subfactors (up to permutation and isomorphism)?

*Remark*: The finite group subfactor case comes from the [Krull–Schmidt theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Krull%E2%80%93Schmidt_theorem). It generalizes into the [Kurosh-Ore theorem](http://planetmath.org/kuroshoretheorem) in the general theory of [modular lattices](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_lattice), with a specific relevant additional result if the lattice is [distributive](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distributive_lattice). Perhaps we can use this theorem for answering the question (at least when the lattice of intermediate subfactors $\mathcal{L}(N\subset M)$ is distributive).